# Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular

I worked on a project(mobile app) with angular2 version 2.0.0-beta.11 and i've work on this project about a 2 years, application is compile and load fine, but when I am login in to my app and routing to dashboard screen it throws 'Maximum call stack size exceeded...' in iOS 12.2 and above version. below version are issue is not appear. If I removed some line from html template then it works like 70kb file size, but if I add some html line in that file and file size is getting 90kb it not working and below error is throw:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum call stack size exceeded. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. ChangeDetector_DashboardComponent_0

viewFactory_DashboardComponent0
viewFactory_HostDashboardComponent0
createHostViewInContainer@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/angular2.dev.js:6723:45
createHostView@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/angular2.dev.js:6205:42
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/angular2.dev.js:12419:55
run@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:18045
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:28176
runTask@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:18749
o@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:15791
invokeTask@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:24729
d@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:7037
v@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/956DEEEF-17A4-43CF-B2C5-1ACB29B8EA76/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-216AAE18-7A5E-40F0-BEB9-994B69237FD5/src/scripts/zone.min.js:1:7277

My package.json:
{
  "name": "Daysi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^1.11.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: we need more context and try to explain youself better

Comment: you should add code of dashboard component to investigate more

Answer (score 0):

It's infinite call happening ,It happens when two components trying to render each other suppose You have given component A's selector in component B's html file  & again you are giving B's selector in component A's html file at that time both component calling each other in loop & memory stack error occur ,Can you share you html code.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue while working with protractor, typescript in one of my project.
this was the issue I had :-

```
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at new Wait (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\utilities\Wait.ts:5:1)
at new SelectDropDown (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\utilities\SelectDropDown.ts:5:1)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:29:23)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
at new CLASS3 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS3.ts:26:25)
at new CLASS1 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS1.ts:30:41)
at new CLASS2 (D:\workspace\DemoProject\latest-code\protractor-cucumber\e2e\com.blog.page\CLASS2.ts:25:32)
```

**Solution** Tech Stack which of my project:-

- Protractor
- Typescript
- Page Object Modal
- Cucumber
- Chai
- node
- npm
- VS Code (IDE)

Circular dependency and circular object creation.
What this means is CLASS1 has object of CLASS2,
CLASS2 has object of CLASS3 and
CLASS3 has object of CLASS1.
Hence this create a circulaR dependency in the code.

https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/unhandled-rejection-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/